# text box value not refreshing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, input

I have a text box that has a default value that disappears onfocus:

```
<input data-role="none" class="search-box" id="addressLookupTxt" type="text" value="City and State or Zipcode" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)" />
```

After entering a text (ie 90210) and submitting the value, when i return to the page with this input, the submitted value is still present.

How can i refresh this value so its the default when i return?

```
$('#CheckInPage').live('pagebeforeshow', function(toPage, fromPage){});
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496301/input-fields-are-retaining-their-values-after-a-page-refresh-how-to-prevent-tha

Comment: Assuming it's not autocomplete text (take a look at the question @ComputerArts linked to) You should be able to just set the text in JS like the following `$('#CheckInPage').live('pagebeforeshow', function(toPage, fromPage){ $('#addressLookupTxt').val(''); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not recommended to create multiple pages in your default/index page when using jquery mobile use

```
 <a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

this will take care of posting back your pages

see [caching pages](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html)